# how to fetch the data from the response like array format using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am newbie in reactjs. it might be a duplicate question. Actuallly i need to show the movie name from imdb file.  Am getting response from the IMDB file. But cant able to show the movie name. Please look at the below code

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
         items: 
         [

         ]
      }

   }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.UserList();
  }

  UserList() {

    fetch('https://theimdbapi.org/api/find/person?name=Kamal+Haasan')
    .then(items=>{
        const posts = items[0].filmography(obj => obj.soundtrack);
        console.log(posts)
        this.setState({ posts })
  }
}

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <div>
               {this.state.items.map((dynamicComponent, i) => <Content 
                  key = {i} componentData = {dynamicComponent}/>)}
            </div>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <div>{this.props.componentData.component}</div>
            <div>{this.props.componentData.id}</div>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Can anone please help on this. I have to show the movie name which i need to get from the API call.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will probably find that the fetch call is returning you a string, not json. You can convert it using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: question, is there a reason why you have `UserList()` as a function outside of componentDidMount when you call it only once?  Why not just call the fetch function in `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: also, i don't see where you close your `.then()` function call....  do you close the curly brace of the arrow function `items=>{`

Comment: @JaeGeeTee Dear closed the then function. cant able to show alert when i put inside then function

Comment: @Mikkel Still is not shows

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with your `fetch` call. `fetch` response is a `readable stream` so you have to read that with the appropriate method. I had done some of the modification in your code. Here is the complete working code to display the movies name.

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }

    this.UserList = this.UserList.bind(this);

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.UserList();
  }

  UserList() {

    fetch('https://theimdbapi.org/api/find/person?name=Kamal+Haasan').then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
      const posts = data[0].filmography.soundtrack;
      this.setState({posts});
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {
            this.state.posts.map((item, i) => {
              return <Content item={item} key={i}/>
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.item.title}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Still am getting issues. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: Response for the service mentioned in the post. please help it out

Comment: [{filmography:{soundtrack:[]}}]